# is that possible to create vbscript file can using the send key and run the program at the same time to execute?

Tags: vbscript

I'm pretty new on the `vbscript`,not sure if I can explain clearly, Please let me know if you need more info to help me out on this , Big Thanks!

I need to execute a adding user program, and that program has to run it under the `cmd` run as admin privilege, at the same time, have to enter the user name at the end in order to make this function normal.

looks like this :

```
c:\windows\ccm\postdeployment\lin\XX.exe "username"   Then enter
```

(was thinking possible to use the `vbscript` to use input box to enter the useranem and execute the command, But i'm not sure how to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
username = InputBox("Enter user name below")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "c:\windows\ccm\postdeployment\lin\XX.exe " & username
```

You should lookup for a online tutorial on WSH

Comment: @MandyHuang 不客气，欢迎多多交流！多多加油！

Comment: Think you're missing a space after the `XX.exe"` to separate the `username` from the program call.

Comment: @Lankymart thanks, indeed you are right. I have just corrected that.